# Using QR Code to enter value into Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form on *Google Form* which is used to record visitors' entry into our Lot. One of the required data for entry is pass number which is in a form of QR code handed to visitors. Is there any ways so that instead of manually typing the pass number, instead just scan the QR code and the pass number will be entered into the form?

I'm aware that it is possible to do it in Sheets, with the following script:

```
function doGet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("sheet_url");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_name");
return insert(e,sheet);

}

function doPost(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("sheet_url");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_name");
return insert(e,sheet);

}


function insert(e,sheet){
 
  var scannedData = e.parameter.sdata;
  var d = new Date();
  var ctime =  d.toLocaleString();
  
  sheet.appendRow([scannedData,ctime]);
```

Therefore, I was hoping if anyone here knows how the script should look like for a form instead.

Comment: I won't be needing timestamp for the QR Code, because the form response will be able to provide that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit the URL of an Apps Script that is deployed as a web app, you are able to pass parameters into the `doGet(e)` function in your script using the `?` parameter after the URL provided when you publish the web app:

```
https://script.google.com/.../exec?passNo=21480&qNumber=1
```

The `e` variable that is taken in by the `doGet()` function is an event object that contains information about the event. [You can acess the parameters from the URL using `e.parameters`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web):

```gas
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log(e.parameters);
}
```

Will display  `{qNumber=[1], passNo=[21480]}` in the logs. These parameters can be extracted and then using the [`FormApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app) library of Apps Script, you can create a new response to the form and submit it programmatically with the [`createResponse().withItemResponse(ItemResponse)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#withItemResponse(ItemResponse)) method of `FormApp`, using the pass number and question number taken from the url parameters:

#### Code.gs:

```gas
function doGet(e){
  try {
    var passNo = e.parameters.passNo;
    var qNumber = e.parameters.qNumber;
    
    var form = FormApp.openById('your-form-id-here');
    var items = form.getItems();

    // assuming question 1 is the pass number question
    var q = items[qNumber[0] - 1].asTextItem();   
    var itemResponse = q.createResponse(passNo[0])
    
    var FormResponse = form.createResponse();    
    FormResponse.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
    FormResponse.submit();
    
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Success')
  }
  catch(e){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Failure'); 
  }
}
```

I've also created two `HTML` files in the project, simply called 'Success.html' and 'Failure.html', and the web app will return the respective page depending on whether the Response creation and submission was successful or not:

#### Success.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Success
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Failure.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Failure
  </body>
</html>
```

Now all you need to do is generate a QR code with the URL of your script and relevant parameters as the locator. Make sure that your `pNumber` parameter in the QR code is *always* set to the number of the question you want to submit to, and that the number after `passNo=` in the URL is the number of the pass you want to scan and input.

Comment: How would I then tell the script on where to enter the value? I'm not that familiar with AppScript with Form, so I'm just a bit confused on that.

Comment: Where are you wanting to enter the value? As a response to the form? You can just pass more parameters! For example you could make the request with parameters something like `https://script.google.com/.../exec?passNo=21480&question=4` and then use the question parameter do specify which form question to pass the `passNo` parameter into. You could also do this with a sheet by using something like a parameter `&cell=a1` and pass the `cell` parameter value into `.getRange(cell).setValue(passNo)`

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't quite get it. Can you show an example for it? Let's say if the first question is where I want the scanned QR Code value to be input to, how do I set the parameter so that the code knows to put the scanned value there?

Comment: Hi @JmeSekaiichi, I've updated my answer to provide a more explanatory solution. Let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

Comment: the `var q = items[qNumber[0] - 1].asTextItem(); ` part was what I didn't get when I was trying to make my own, thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: No worries, glad to be able to help! `e.parameters` becomes a list of single-element arrays each of which containing the parameter you send, so you have to make sure you're accessing the right element for each use.