# How to scan a QR Code to Import the Info Into Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, qr-code, google-forms

I want to start off by saying I have limited coding experience in google scripts, but have had extensive experience coding in R. I have tried a using previous stackedoverflow solution ([Using QR Code to enter value into Google Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198579/using-qr-code-to-enter-value-into-google-form)), but any time I would edit the URL, it'll say "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time."

I copied the code that was listed under code.gs into the main script and changed 'your-form-id-here' to match my google sheet's ID and added the two HTML codes for 'Success' and 'Failure', but it hasn't worked.

I have a google form that asks people to input their unique ID Number. Rather than having folks mis-type their number, I would like to set it up so that they can scan a QR code on their phone and have the Google Form auto-populate the first question that asks for their ID#. There are additional questions on the google form they need to answer, but I would just like for the first question to be auto-populated.

Here is the Google Form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdsP0e2FsC54QY0Nyrpipi21yC-8ODjO9aRlfOMq51vODRaew/viewform?usp=sf_link

The Form ID I used was 1FAIpQLSdsP0e2FsC54QY0Nyrpipi21yC-8ODjO9aRlfOMq51vODRaew, which I assumed was the ID based on the Google Form URL.

**EDIT: Here is my current script for the Code.gs:**

```
function doGet(e){
  try {
    var passNo = e.parameters.passNo;
    var qNumber = e.parameters.qNumber;
    
    var form = FormApp.openById('1FAIpQLSdsP0e2FsC54QY0Nyrpipi21yC-8ODjO9aRlfOMq51vODRaew');
    var items = form.getItems();

    // assuming question 1 is the pass number question
    var q = items[qNumber[0] - 1].asTextItem();   
    var itemResponse = q.createResponse(passNo[0])
    
    var FormResponse = form.createResponse();    
    FormResponse.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
    FormResponse.submit();
    
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Success')
  }
  catch(e){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Failure'); 
  }
}
```

**I also added the Success.html and Failure.html code exactly as written in the previous example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Success
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Failure
  </body>
</html>
```

After deploying the script, I got the URL and practiced adding the "passNo" and "qNumber" exactly as they did in the example by adding `?passNo=21480&qNumber=1` to the end of my URL, but the URL leads to a page error:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx9oXtjZXGNHPN1axSjKvP5StGbBej0IbQzK1vNT-HB6hzEvIzDbcLor-qtgVDU3ftQ/exec?passNo=1234&qNumber=1

Comment: For example, if you are using the same script with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57203110), about `changed 'your-form-id-here' to match my google sheet's ID`, in this case, it's mean of `var form = FormApp.openById('your-form-id-here');`? If my understanding is correct, I think that the value of `your-form-id-here` is required to be the Google Form ID. I'm worried about it. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide your current script including the explanation?

Comment: see edits above!

Comment: Thank you for repliyng and providing your current script. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue and solution:

When I saw your current script, I noticed that at `ar form = FormApp.openById('1FAIpQLSdsP0e2FsC54QY0Nyrpipi21yC-8ODjO9aRlfOMq51vODRaew');` and `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdsP0e2FsC54QY0Nyrpipi21yC-8ODjO9aRlfOMq51vODRaew/viewform?usp=sf_link`, you are using the ID from the URL of preview. In this case, that ID is not the Google Form ID. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

For example, when I tested your script by using the correct Google Form ID, no error occurs. "Success" is returned. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('1FAIpQLSdsP0e2FsC54QY0Nyrpipi21yC-8ODjO9aRlfOMq51vODRaew');
```

#### To:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('### Google Form ID ###');
```

- In this case, please use `###` of `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/###/edit`.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".